# how Do I make a new line in React Like a terminal

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

## What am I using

> React, CSS modules

Hi There I am making a `Portfolio Terminal` website

So, I want to make a feature where the user creates a *new Line* like the terminal does so, when you press enter in the terminal it creates a new line like this: [Terminal New Line Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLJW9.png)

So, as I was saying I want this same functionality but there is a problem I face where when I press enter and then try to do another command it doesn't do the **command**

I hope I made this clear

here is my ***JSX*** code:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import styles from "../css/TerminalPage.module.css";

function TerminalPage() {
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState("");
  const [helpValues, setHelpValues] = useState("");
  const [newLine, setNewLine] = useState("");
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const help = {
    about: "My Name Is Ammar Ehab and I am a Full-Stack Developer",
    social: {
      title: "YouTube",
      url: "www.youtube.com",
    },
    projects: {
      title: "Projects",
      url: "www.yourprojectsurl.com", // Replace with your actual projects URL
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleKeyDown(event) {
      if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 76) {
        event.preventDefault();
        setHelpValues("");
      }
    }

    function handleClick() {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
    // Add the event listener when the component mounts
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    window.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

    // Remove the event listener when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
      window.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    };
  }, []);

  function renderSocialLink() {
    const socialTitle = help.social.title;
    const socialUrl = help.social.url;

    return (
      <div className={styles.gridContainer}>
        <div className={styles.gridItem}>
          <span>{socialTitle}</span>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.gridItem}>
          <span className={styles.gridItemUrl}>{socialUrl}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  function checkHelpCommand() {
    const trimmedInput = textInput.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (trimmedInput === "help") {
      const commands = Object.keys(help);
      setHelpValues(
        commands.map((command, index) => <span key={index}>{command}</span>)
      );
    } else if (trimmedInput === "about") {
      setHelpValues(help.about);
    } else if (trimmedInput === "social") {
      setHelpValues(renderSocialLink());
    } else if (trimmedInput === "clear") {
      setHelpValues("");
    } else if (trimmedInput === "") {
      setNewLine("newLine");
    } else {
      setHelpValues(
        `command not found ${trimmedInput}. Type "help" for more information`
      );
    }
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkHelpCommand();
    setTextInput("");
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.terminalContainer}>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <div className={styles.terminalInputContainer}>
          <div>
            <span className={styles.terminalKeyword}>
              guest<span>@</span>ammar.com:<span>~$</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <input
            value={textInput}
            onChange={(e) => setTextInput(e.target.value)}
            ref={inputRef}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <div>
            <div className={styles.textareaOutput}>
              {Array.isArray(helpValues)
                ? helpValues.map((element, index) => (
                    <div key={index} className={styles.commandBlock}>
                      {element}
                    </div>
                  ))
                : helpValues}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style={{ display: "block" }}>
            {newLine === "newLine" ? (
              <div className={styles.terminalInputContainer}>
                <div>
                  <span className={styles.terminalKeyword}>
                    guest<span>@</span>ammar.com:<span>~$</span>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <input
                  value={textInput}
                  onChange={(e) => setTextInput(e.target.value)}
                  ref={inputRef}
                />
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TerminalPage;
```

and here are my styles if needed:

```css
:root {
  --main-text-color: #a16b56;
  --text-input-color: #73abad;
  --main-color: #e2d7a7;
  --text-url-hover: #1a4645;
  --text-url-color: #f8bc24;
  --user-text-color: rgb(81, 153, 117);
}

.terminalContainer {
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.terminalContainer * {
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.terminalContainer .input-container {
  position: relative;
}

.terminalContainer .input-container::before {
  content: "visitor@Ammar:$ ~ ";
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.terminalContainer input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  color: var(--text-input-color);
  /* Add a text-shadow for the glow effect */
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(115, 171, 173, 0.5); /* Adjust the values as needed */
}

.terminalContainer input:hover {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: text;
}

.terminalContainer textarea:hover,
.terminalContainer input:hover {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: text;
}

.terminalInputContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.terminalInputContainer div .terminalKeyword {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-size: large;
}

.terminalKeyword {
  color: var(--user-text-color);
}

.terminalKeyword span {
  color: var(--main-text-color);
}

.terminalInputContainer input {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: var(--text-input-color);
}

.textareaOutput {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.gridContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 500px;
}

.gridItemUrl {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  width: fit-content;
  color: var(--text-url-color);
  padding: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gridItemUrl:hover {
  background-color: var(--text-url-hover);
}

/* Grid items within the container */
.gridItem {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: var(--main-text-color);
}

.gridItem span {
  display: block; /* Display URLs on a new line */
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.commandBlock {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: var(--text-input-color);
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(115, 171, 173, 0.5),
    0 0 10px rgba(115, 171, 173, 0.5), 0 0 15px rgba(115, 171, 173, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Hey, I don't understood your requirement, You want to enter new line when user press enter, just this OR something else you've asked for ?

Comment: no just this I want to make it where if I press enter it creates a new line like in the image and I can use the commands when I create the new line if you need more clarification you can check out [https://term.m4tt72.com/] I am trying to create something like this website

Comment: Hey, I fixed your example as well as some CSS to look it more better, I am posting an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-7dsyf2?file=/demo.js

=> Here, I have added one more state called "**inputHistory**" to store precious entered commands. (Same as Terminal)

**Here, is the Updated JSX code:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import styles from "./TerminalPage.module.css";

function Demo() {
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState("");
  const [helpValues, setHelpValues] = useState([]);
  const [inputHistory, setInputHistory] = useState([]);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const help = {
    about: "My Name Is Ammar Ehab and I am a Full-Stack Developer",
    social: {
      title: "YouTube",
      url: "www.youtube.com"
    },
    projects: {
      title: "Projects",
      url: "www.yourprojectsurl.com" // Replace with your actual projects URL
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleKeyDown(event) {
      if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 76) {
        event.preventDefault();
        setHelpValues([]);
      }
    }

    function handleClick() {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }

    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    window.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
      window.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    };
  }, []);

  function renderSocialLink() {
    const socialTitle = help.social.title;
    const socialUrl = help.social.url;

    return (
      <div className={styles.gridContainer}>
        <div className={styles.gridItem}>
          <span>{socialTitle}</span>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.gridItem}>
          <span className={styles.gridItemUrl}>{socialUrl}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function executeCommand(command) {
    const trimmedInput = command.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (trimmedInput === "help") {
      const commands = Object.keys(help);
      setHelpValues(commands);
    } else if (trimmedInput === "about") {
      setHelpValues([help.about]);
    } else if (trimmedInput === "social") {
      setHelpValues([renderSocialLink()]);
    } else if (trimmedInput === "clear") {
      setHelpValues([]);
    } else {
      setHelpValues([
        `command not found ${trimmedInput}. Type "help" for more information`
      ]);
    }
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (textInput.trim() !== "") {
      executeCommand(textInput);
    }

    // Add the current input to the input history for future track
    setInputHistory([...inputHistory, textInput]);

    setTextInput("");
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.terminalContainer}>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <div className={styles.terminalInputContainer}>
          {inputHistory.map((command, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <span className={styles.terminalKeyword}>
                guest<span>@</span>ammar.com:<span>~$</span>
              </span>
              {command}
            </div>
          ))}
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
              alignItems: "center"
            }}
          >
            <span className={styles.terminalKeyword}>
              guest<span>@</span>ammar.com:<span>~$</span>
            </span>

            <input
              value={textInput}
              onChange={(e) => setTextInput(e.target.value)}
              ref={inputRef}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.textareaOutput}>
          {Array.isArray(helpValues)
            ? helpValues.map((element, index) => (
                <div key={index} className={styles.commandBlock}>
                  {element}
                </div>
              ))
            : helpValues}
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Demo;
```

**Here, is the Updated CSS code:**

```
:root {
  --main-text-color: #a16b56;
  --text-input-color: #73abad;
  --main-color: #e2d7a7;
  --text-url-hover: #1a4645;
  --text-url-color: #f8bc24;
  --user-text-color: rgb(81, 153, 117);
}

.terminalContainer {
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.terminalContainer * {
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.terminalContainer .input-container {
  position: relative;
}

.terminalContainer .input-container::before {
  content: "visitor@Ammar:$ ~ ";
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.terminalContainer input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  /* background-color: var(--main-color); */
  color: var(--text-input-color);
  /* Add a text-shadow for the glow effect */
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(115, 171, 173, 0.5); /* Adjust the values as needed */
}

.terminalContainer input:hover {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: text;
}

.terminalContainer textarea:hover,
.terminalContainer input:hover {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: text;
}

.terminalInputContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  flex-direction: column;
}

.terminalInputContainer div .terminalKeyword {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-size: large;
}

.terminalKeyword {
  color: var(--user-text-color);
}

.terminalKeyword span {
  color: var(--main-text-color);
}

.terminalInputContainer input {
  width: 100%;
  /* margin: 0 0 0 5px; */
  /* height: 100px; */
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: var(--text-input-color);
}

.textareaOutput {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.gridContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 500px;
}

.gridItemUrl {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  width: fit-content;
  color: var(--text-url-color);
  padding: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gridItemUrl:hover {
  background-color: var(--text-url-hover);
}

/* Grid items within the container */
.gridItem {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: var(--main-text-color);
}

.gridItem span {
  display: block; /* Display URLs on a new line */
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.commandBlock {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: var(--text-input-color);
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(115, 171, 173, 0.5),
    0 0 10px rgba(115, 171, 173, 0.5), 0 0 15px rgba(115, 171, 173, 0.5);
}
```

Let me know, If you have any doubts.